# Facebook SDK - Tagging photo error #121

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a photo to a user's Facebook and then tag that user in the same photo, I have tried a few methods but none seem to work.  The photo will upload via this method it just doesnt assign the tags.  I don't know how to make another call to tag the photo as I also get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException:
>   (#121) Invalid photo id thrown in
>   /sdk/base_facebook.php on line 970

Here is my code:

```
$tag = array(
        'tag_uid' => $facebook->getUser(),
        'x' => 0,
        'y' => 0
    );
    $tags[] = $tag;
$args = array(
  'message' => 'caption',
  'image' => '@'.realpath("watch.jpg"),
  'tags' => $tags,
);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because I didn't have the `user_photos` permission set!

Comment: and you also need 'user_photo_video_tags'